# Where is data stored during an Android test?

Tags: android-testing, android-jetpack-datastore

I am providing a `DataStore<Preferences>` to be able to conveniently edit preferences.

```
/**
 * Default data store
 */
val Context.settingsDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

/**
 * Dummy datastore for compositionLocalOf
 */
val dummyDataStore = object : DataStore<Preferences> {
    override val data: Flow<Preferences>
        get() = TODO("Not yet implemented")

    override suspend fun updateData(transform: suspend (t: Preferences) -> Preferences): Preferences {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

/**
 * CompositionLocal providing a datastore
 */
val LocalDataStore = compositionLocalOf { dummyDataStore } // TODO use static?

@Composable
fun DataStoreProvider(
    dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> = LocalContext.current.settingsDataStore,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) =
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDataStore.provides(dataStore)) { content() }
```

During a test, where is the data stored?

```
    @Test
    fun togglesOnClick() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            DataStoreProvider {
                SwitchPreference(title = "Title", preference = BooleanPreference("test"))
            }
        }

        composeTestRule.onRoot().printToLog("provider-test")
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Title").performClick()
        composeTestRule.onRoot().printToLog("provider-test")
    }
```

Running the test opens the following screen, which doesn't seem to be an app that can be deleted.

[image: test screen]

I confirmed that the data is stored permanently.

```
    @Test
    fun togglesOnClick() = runBlocking{
        val preference = BooleanPreference("test2")
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            DataStoreProvider {
                SwitchPreference(title = "Title", preference = preference)

                val state = preference.state()
                Log.d(TAG, "state: ${state.value}")
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Title").performClick() // toggles the state
        delay(5000) // don't know how to properly wait yet
    }
```

```
023-06-16 18:56:51.672 17529-17529 provider-test           pid-17529                            D  state: null
2023-06-16 18:56:51.732 17529-17529 provider-test           pid-17529                            D  state: true
2023-06-16 18:58:36.505 21914-21914 provider-test           com...ntial.composepreferences.test  D  state: null
2023-06-16 18:58:36.561 21914-21914 provider-test           com...ntial.composepreferences.test  D  state: false
2023-06-16 18:59:10.621 23567-23567 provider-test           com...ntial.composepreferences.test  D  state: null
2023-06-16 18:59:10.679 23567-23567 provider-test           com...ntial.composepreferences.test  D  state: true
```

If the data is stored separately from the actual application, I am wondering if it's even worth it to implement an in-memory version of `DataStore` over simply calling `clear` before each test. (I come from React/Node.js where in-memory database mocks are necessary to not interfere with files on your computer)

[Repo](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/compose-preferences)